# Errors caused by running a C program containing file operation using notepad++

Tags: c, windows, notepad++

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("text.txt", "w");
    char c;
    while ((c = getchar()) != '!') {
        if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z')
            c -= 32;
        fputc(c, fp);
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Whether I run it from the command line or directly click the executable file, it can run successfully. But if I use the notepad++ Run option，type the following command, `cmd /k $(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)\$(NAME_PART).exe $(FULL_CURRENT_PATH & PAUSE & EXIT`,it will cause an error. Specifically, It compiles successfully,but after i running it,I cannot see the created file.What caused the error? And how to solve it?

Comment: what's the error?

Comment: If you wrote it in notepad and then attempt to compile with MinGW (gcc) it will not work because notepad saves with a UTF-16 encoding with BOM. gcc will handle UTF-8, but not UTF-16. If you compiles successfully, then you have a runtime error. What compiler are you using? Also `$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH & PAUSE & EXIT"` definitely looks wrong.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Notepad++ (or notepad) will not save UTF-16 unless you specifically set it to do so. And if you did, you can change it back.

Comment: @yano.I added in the question.

Comment: Did you check other directories? The current working directory might not be the one you think it is.

Comment: Probably it's running in another working directory, simply. `test.txt` is a relative path.

Comment: The file is likely created in whatever directory `cmd /k` launched in. If there was an error about not being able to create the file, that would reflect that `cmd /k` launched in some directory where you have no write permission (like something under `windows` or `win32`?)  Check the command line options for `cmd`, I know you can set the initial present working directory there.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin.I found the file in the Notepad installation directory.At first,I thought it would be on drive C,but i am wrong.

Comment: Make it a habit to always store the result of `getchar()` in an `int`.